# How can I extract the dates and time in particular table .. the output will be before and after based on the date today and create csv files on them

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, aws-lambda

Here are my query samples. I made a sample comparing the dates but the output I expected is not meant to be how can I do it I already get the results but I want them to extract per rows and make before and after dates that will be based on today.

```
    cur = cnxn.cursor()
    
    query = """ 
    SELECT A.CaseNumber,A.AppointmentDateTime,A.AppointmentType,A.AppointmentInterviewType,B.ClientInfoData 
    FROM ASPEN.tbl_Appointment A LEFT JOIN ASPEN.tbl_ClientInfo B ON A.CaseNumber = B.CaseNumber 
    ORDER BY B.CaseNumber, B.ClientInfoSortOrder
    """
    
    d1, m1, y1 = [int(x) for x in input("query").split('/')]
  
    b1 = date(y1, m1, d1)
      
    # Input for second date
    d2, m2, y2 = [int(x) for x in input("query").split('/')]
      
    b2 = date(y2, m2, d2)    
    
    cur.execute(query)
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    print (rows)
    
   #Save the Query results to a CSV file
    bucket_name = os.environ['BUCKET_NAME']
    mst = dateutil.tz.gettz('US/Mountain')
    file_name = datetime.now(tz=mst).strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '.csv'
    print (file_name)
    fp = open('/tmp/Processlist.csv', 'w')
    myFile = csv.writer(fp)
    myFile.writerows(rows)
    fp.close()
```

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3) "B" is *not* for "tbl_ClientInfo"

Comment: As for your question, what is it? What isn't working about what you have? You say the results aren't what you expect; *why* aren't they what you expected?

Comment: my question regarding on this is on the query side is there any othery coding way to do it

Comment: To do *what*? You haven't explained what isn't working.

Comment: Just like this for example 

 if (A.AppointmentDateTime > datetime.date(datetime.now()))):
        print("Before")
    elif (datetime.date < A.AppointmentDateTime):
        print("After")
    else:
        print("Dates are equal") 


So just want  to expect on the console will 
before and after on the current date and time :)

Comment: Sorry, but your explanation is still unclear. ("want to expect on the console will before and after on the current date and time"??)